# В чем разница между `short int` и `int16_t`?

Tags: c++

Смотрел курс по `C++` на **Coursera** и там рассказали, что можно подключить библиотеку `cstdlib` и использовать типы данных типа: `int16_t, uint16_t, int64_t, uint64_t` и т.д. Недавно узнал что в плюсах также как же писать просто `short int, long int` и т.д.

Вопрос собственно в том, что есть ли разница между ними или это одно и то же?

Comment: Примите один из ответов, если он решил вопрос

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В зависимости от компилятора и системы, под которую вы компилируете, размер встроенных типов (`short`, `int`, `long`, и т.д., в противоположность `intXX_t`, `uintXX_t`) может отличаться.

В стандарте (или еще где-то) можете почитать, в каких пределах могут меняться размеры этих типов, но на практике обычно `short` - 2 байта, `int` - 4, `long` - 4 или 8, `long long` - 8.

А у `intXX_t` и `uintXX_t`, очевидно, размер всегда одинаковый.

Comment: Все что про них очевидно — что это вообще говоря разные типы.

Answer (score 4):

`short int` и `long int` - стандартные языковые типы размеров не менее 16 и не менее 32, соответственно.

`int16_t` и `int32_t` - опционально поддерживаемые алиасы типов из стандартной библиотеки размеров ровно 16 и ровно 32, соответственно.

Кстати, `char8_t`, `char16_t` и `char32_t` относятся именно к первому типу (т.е. ключевые слова нефиксированного размера), несмотря на название.

Доки:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

Comment: разве когда я пишу `short int`  не выделяется фиксированное кол-во памяти в стеке размером 16 бит?

Comment: @toiepp зависит от реализации. На конкретной реализации они фиксированные, конечно. Но на одной может быть 16, на другой 32, я об этом